# php obtaining complex file extension like mysql-5.0.1.tar.gz

Tags: php, file, upload

I've run into a typical problem here. Till now i was doing

```
strstr($filename,".");
```

$filename is the file i got from $_FILE i.e uploaded file.It was running fine until i hit a filename of the type i mentioned.
Even doing

```
pathinfo($filename);
```

gives me

```
.gz
```

I need to see whether it is EXACTLY

```
.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple way would be to check for the last 7 characters of the filename - this ensures that every file ends with `.tar.gz`:

```
if (substr($filename, -7) == '.tar.gz') {
    // continue
}
```

Comment: Is this the answer?
I can't believe my eyes

Comment: You made my day, Stefan)

Answer (score 4):

Technically, `pathinfo` is correct: the one and only extension for that file is `.gz`. The fact that it has `.tar` in the name is as coincidental as the fact that it has `5.0.1` in it.

That doesn't make your interest in checking for `.tar.gz` files invalid, but it does raise the question: what specifically do you want to find?

The most direct solution to your specific question is: first look for the extension (via `pathinfo` or the [strpos](http://us.php.net/strrpos) function) and then if it happens to be `.gz` look for the "extension" in the remaining filename (via the same technique).

```
$parts = pathinfo($filename);
$extension = $parts['extension'];
if ($extension == '.gz') {
    $parts = pathinfo($parts['filename']);
    $extension = $parts['extension'] . $extension;
}
```

Comment: i am ONLY looking for files with extension .tar.gz , i.e they should end with .tar.gz. So any file like this.is.a.long.filename.tar.gz should be valid..

Answer (score 0):

And if you needed to parse 'this.is.a.very.long.file.name.with.lots.of.full.stops' then what part of that is the file extension? Relying on a particular part of a filename to convey semantic, machine readable information about the contents of the file is, at best dangerous.

It's not clear what the problem you are trying is - why do you need to know what the extension is?

C.

Comment: I have an upload form where i am restricting the user to upload ONLY .tar.gz archives. No other file type has to be allowed. So when he uploads something like mysql-5.0.1.tar.gz, my script says invalid file type because of the above logic. I need the extract the ".tar.gz" part from that file name. :)

Comment: ...so your solution is not fit for purpose - since the name of a file has nothing to do with its contents. If you want to validate the contents check that 'tar -tvzf $uploaded_file' returns no errors. And force a filename ending in .tar.gz or tgz on download.

Comment: Yeah content validation is done later. If extraction fails i return an error.I am just checking if the file extension is .tar.gz. Basically saves a step. Shouldn't even bother extracting if its not .tar.gz. Not a very healthy way but it'll do .. So if the user deliberately names a file ending with tar.gz its gonna fail while extraction.

Comment: Then check strripos($filename, '.tar.gz')==strlen('.tar.gz')

Answer (score 0):

I just posted the following enhanced version of `pathinfo()` in comments over on [PHP.net](http://php.net/pathinfo). This version groups all of the parts of the file extension in as the extension (e.g. "tar.gz" instead of just "gz"), leaving the rest as the filename:

```
<?php
  function pathinfo_enhanced($file_path) {
    $core_path_info = pathinfo($file_path);
    $filename = $core_path_info['filename'];

    if (isset($core_path_info['extension'])) {
      $extension = $core_path_info['extension'];
    } else {
      $extension = '';
    }

    $extension_parts = array();

    while (!empty($extension)) {
      array_unshift($extension_parts, $extension);

      $remaining_path_info = pathinfo($filename);
      $filename = $remaining_path_info['filename'];

      if (isset($remaining_path_info['extension'])) {
        $extension = $remaining_path_info['extension'];
      } else {
        $extension = '';
      }
    }

    $revised_path_info = array(
      'filename'  => $filename,
      'extension' => implode('.', $extension_parts),
    );

    return array_merge($core_path_info, $revised_path_info);
  }
```

Here are some examples you can run to show how it handles the different cases:

```
  // Directory; two extensions
  $path = '/www/htdocs/inc/file.tar.gz';
  $info = pathinfo_enhanced($path);

  echo "$path\n";
  print_r($info);
  echo "\n";

  // Directory; one extension
  $path = '/www/htdocs/inc/file.tgz';
  $info = pathinfo_enhanced($path);

  echo "$path\n";
  print_r($info);
  echo "\n";

  // Directory; no extension
  $path = '/www/htdocs/inc/lib';
  $info = pathinfo_enhanced($path);

  echo "$path\n";
  print_r($info);
  echo "\n";

  // No directory; one extension
  $path = 'test.php';
  $info = pathinfo_enhanced($path);

  echo "$path\n";
  print_r($info);
  echo "\n";

  // No directory; dot file
  $path = '.example';
  $info = pathinfo_enhanced($path);

  echo "$path\n";
  print_r($info);
  echo "\n";

  // Directory only
  $path = '/www/htdocs/inc/';
  $info = pathinfo_enhanced($path);

  echo "$path\n";
  print_r($info);
  echo "\n";
```

Answer (score -2):

THIS is the answer:

```
strstr(pathinfo('asdasd/qweqwe/asdasd.tar.gz')['basename'], '.');
```

will return you '.tar.gz'